# Finding $\iint_A xy\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$, where $\small A=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: 0\leq x\leq a \wedge 0\leq y\leq b\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find $\iint_A xy\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$, where $A=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: 0\leq x\leq a \wedge 0\leq y\leq b\}$.

The correct answer should be $a^2b^2/4$, how do I get there using Fubini's theorem?

Comment: You need to show that what you've done solving your question. Otherwise it'll get closed by the policy of this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By fubini's theorem the given integral is equal to $\int_{x=0}^a xdx ×\int_{y=0}^b ydy$. I think you can get it now.